# How do I fix the cursor to the middle of the screen in Emacs, so that the page moves, not the cursor?

Tags: emacs, scroll, elisp

I'd like to fix the cursor to the centre line of the screen, so that when I press Ctrl-N or Ctrl-P, the page itself moves up or down, and the cursor stays still.

Has anyone got any tips on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Ed

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try centered-cursor mode:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/centered-cursor-mode.el

If you're using [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/), it's available by <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-install` <kbd>RET</kbd> `centered-cursor-mode`.

Comment: Thank you.  That's absolutely perfect.  He seems to have really got it working nicely there.

Answer (score 11):

`M-x scroll-lock-mode`, which could be used to put the Scroll Lock key to good use too:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<Scroll_Lock>") 'scroll-lock-mode)
```

Comment: Please replace that typographical quotes with the valid ones.

Answer (score 4):

The EmacsWiki page on [SmoothScrolling](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SmoothScrolling) presents some possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can roll your own using the [recenter](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Recentering.html) built-in:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-n")
        (lambda (n)
          (interactive "p")
          (next-line n)
          (recenter)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-p")
        (lambda (n)
          (interactive "p")
          (previous-line n)
          (recenter)))
```