# Why is recenter-top-bottom on every movement not standard in emacs?

Tags: emacs, macros

I am now considering to change all functions that move the cursor to also, automatically, recenter after each move, `recenter-top-bottom`. Why is this not standard, is it bad practice?

Try it out with recording a macro of `<down>` and `C-l`, and then replaying it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892378/how-do-i-fix-the-cursor-to-the-middle-of-the-screen-in-emacs-so-that-the-page-m

Comment: I believe it is not a duplicate because the question is mostly about the why or why not

Comment: I gave you a plus one for showing an easier way to implement it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the biggest reason that it's not "standard" is because it entails a lot of redraw, which was historically something to be avoided whenever possible (updating two characters in the terminal is dramatically more efficient than updating all characters in the terminal).

Comment: Does that mean you have it turned on?

Comment: I do have bindings for the following: `(defun scroll-one-line-ahead ()
  "Scroll ahead one line"
  (interactive)
  (scroll-up 1)
  (forward-line 1))

(defun scroll-one-line-back ()
  "Scroll back one line"
  (interactive)
  (scroll-down 1)
  (forward-line -1))`